# How can I cut out a section of a string using Perl?

Tags: perl

I need to cut some characters out of the middle of a string; the starting and ending positions of the character sequence to be cut will vary.

For example, say I have the sentence

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

I need to count forward from the first character until I get to `fox`, assign the character position of the `f` to a variable, continue counting forward until I get to 'the' and then cut out the characters between and including the initial `f` and the final `e`.

#### Note

There is an `e` in `jumped` which is between `fox` and `the`, this should be ignored, it must find the position of the `e` in `the`.

Comment: Normally, you provide evidence that you've attempted to solve this yourself

Comment: I'm new to perl. All the research I have found relates to using length which, as far as I can tell, cannot be used inside strings. Therefore, I had no clue what to do and came to a knowledge base, feel free to downvote for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove a section of a string where you're not sure of all the intervening characters, you can use the [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2f_PATTERN_%2f_REPLACEMENT_%2fmsixpodualngcer). If there's a match, the position of the beginning of the match (zero-indexed) is stored in [`$-[0]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40LAST_MATCH_START) (or `$LAST_MATCH_START[0]` if you `use English;`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
$string =~ s/fox.*the//;

say "Matched at char $-[0]" if defined $-[0];
say "New string: $string";
```

#### Output:

```
Matched at char 16
New string: The quick brown  lazy dog
```

---

### Which "the"?

Note that the regex I used is greedy, so it will gobble up every `the` until the last. For the string:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and the sleepy cat
```

you will get:

```
Matched at char 16
New string: The quick brown  sleepy cat
```

To stop at the first occurrence of `the`, change the substitution to:

```
s/fox.*?the//;
```

### Whole words only

Both of the regexes above will still match partial words. The string:

```
The quick brown foxhole jumped over their lazy dog
```

gives:

```
Matched at char 16
New string: The quick brown ir lazy dog
```

To only match whole words* change the substitution to:

```
s/(?:^|\s+)\Kfox\s+.*\s+the(?=\s+|\z)//; # greedy
```

or

```
s/(?:^|\s+)\Kfox\s+.*?\s+the(?=\s+|\z)//; # non-greedy
```

---

* It's hard to define what counts as a whole word in an English sentence. The above expects a word to be surrounded on both sides by one or more spaces or to be at the beginning or end of the string, which excludes things like `in-the-know`, but also excludes `"fox"` and `the,`. This is obviously not a great definition.

Comment: Thank you, this should help a lot

Comment: Remember, sometimes [Using \b in regex patterns can lead to surprising results](http://www.nu42.com/2012/04/using-b-in-regex-patterns-can-lead-to.html).

Comment: @SinanÜnür Ugh, thanks for reminding me. Parsing natural-language "words" with regexes is \*so\* error-prone, it's an exercise in futility (or something like that...) Case-in-point, my previous sentence. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have the sentence
>
> > The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
>
> I need to count forward from the first character until I get to 'fox', asign the character position of 'f' to a variable, continue counting forward until I get to 'the' and then cut out the characters, including and between, 'f' and 'e'.

I am quoting your problem description because it indicates the C mindset with which you are approaching Perl. At a bit higher level than C, your problem is to actually to cut out the words between "brown" and "lazy". Perl allows you to directly express this idea:

```
 $ perl -wE 'say join(" ", (split /\s+(?:fox|the)\s+/, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")[0, 2])'
The quick brown lazy dog
```

Or, using the range operator:

```
$ perl -wE 'say join " ", grep !(/^fox$/ .. /^the$/), split " ", "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"'
The quick brown lazy dog
```

which literally reads "take all the words *not* between 'fox' and 'the', join them together using a single space as the word separator, and print the resulting sentence."

If the original sentence has many, *many* words, the first one might be more efficient as it will only ever create a three element list.

You can read more about the [range operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Range-Operators) in `perldoc perlop`. Since you are just beginning to learn Perl, you should read everything mentioned in `perldoc perltoc` at least once, including all the FAQ sections.

Comment: Nice. Way to address the X instead of the Y. I think these are probably closer to what the OP really wants.